# How to find out what # you are for google keyword

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to form a Google query to quickly find out what position you are for a search term.

I know that Google Webmaster Tools and Google Analytics has something similar but I don't find it accurate.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the keywords that you want to check the position of then you can use any of the following:

- [SEO Centro](http://www.seocentro.com/tools/search-engines/keyword-position.html)
- [Moonsy Google Keyword Rank Checker](http://moonsy.com/google-keyword-rank-checker/)
- [Allorank](http://www.allorank.com/check-position)
- [Google Rank Checker](http://www.googleposition.com/)
- [Google Page Rank](http://arizonawebdevelopment.com/google-page-rank)
- [Google, Bing and Yahoo Keyword Rank Checker](http://smallseotools.com/keyword-position/)

If you want detailed reports on all the keywords and positions that you may not even be aware of your ranking for... then sadly your need to look at a paid service, you can get such reports using some of the following sites:following:

- [SEOMoz](http://www.seomoz.org/)
- [Web CEO](http://www.webceo.com/)
- [SEO Profiler](http://www.seoprofiler.com/)
- [WooRank](http://www.woorank.com/)

To check the difference between them you can take a look at [Raven vs SeoProfiler vs SEOMoz](http://blog.seoprofiler.com/2012/12/raven-vs-seoprofiler-vs-seomoz/), its worth noting that while these display keyword rankings they also offer many other solutions how to rank better, there may be a cheaper option than these without the other perks but I don't know of any so maybe someone else can help if your on a tight budget.

Comment: It should be noted that any "rank checker" is certain to break Google's TOS.